# Fish Shell - Init Git repo yields constant terminal output after every command

Tags: git, shell, unix, terminal, fish

This abruptly started happening a few weeks ago. I wasn't paying much attention to when it happened so I'm not sure what commands led to this. However, it appears to only happen inside of git repos, but immediately upon `cd`ing into a git repo my shell immediately prints the following:

`string match: Regular expression compile error: quantifier does not follow a repeatable item
string match: *
string match: ^`

and continues to do so after **every** command, not just git commands. It also occurs when I create a new folder, initialize an empty git repo inside it, then add a single file by some means (e.g. Nano, Vim, etc.). Immediately upon saving and closing the file my terminal outputs this `string match` mumbo-jumbo...

I've been able to find the fish shell code that outputs this error [here](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/master/pcre2-10.21/src/pcre2_error.c), but haven't been able to trace it back to anything yet. Also, if I switch back to the bash shell the issue does not reproduce.

*System Info:* This occurs on both of my Mac's (1 Mac Mini, 1 Macbook Pro) both running macOS Sierra.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Probably this is coming from your prompt. What does `functions fish_prompt` show?

Comment: @ridiculous_fish Edited to include this output.

Comment: Woah! Changing the fish prompt does indeed get rid of this issue! I would never have guessed. Thanks so much! @ridiculous_fish

Comment: FWIW, the error was coming from the `string match -r \*` in your prompt function. A bare asterisk isn't a valid PCRE regex. You can see this for yourself by typing `string match -r \* hello`.

Comment: Do not edit your question to specify **SOLVED**. Instead, add an answer (as a separate answer, outside the question; questions should not include answers!), and mark that answer as accepted.

Comment: Alternately, if you think the resolution wouldn't be helpful to anyone else, you can simply delete your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Updated my fish prompt using the fish_config editor, and the problem has been fixed!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the @halfer answer, I found out `AcidHub` prompt is leading to this error.

Choosing a different prompt solves the problem.

[Edit]

According to this [commit](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/commit/1a1a9b9927fea2393256e05af93dbdc0095d54d1) on Github, this has been fixed 26 days ago but no release since November so we might have to wait a little bit to get the fix.

In the meantime, if you love as much as I do this prompt and don't wanna wait the next release, you could copy the latest acidhub.fish (from the repo) in your own fish_config folder which is `~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish` :)